# Combine several bool pandas.Series with uncommon indices with an logical and

Tags: pandas

### The Problem:

I have a list of `pandas.Series`, where the series all have dates as index, but it is not guaranteed that they all have the same index.
The values are guaranteed to be bools (no NaNs possible).

The result i want to get is one `pandas.Series` where the index is the union of all indices found in the list of series. The value for each index should be the logical and of all series values, which contain the index.

### Example:

```
A = pd.Series(index=[datetime(2015,05,01,20),
                     datetime(2015,05,01,20,15),
                     datetime(2015,05,01,20,30)],
              data=[False, True, True])
B = pd.Series(index=[datetime(2015,05,01,20),
                     datetime(2015,05,01,20,30),
                     datetime(2015,05,01,20,45)],
              data=[True, True, True])
series = [A, B]
```

A common index is `datetime(2015,05,01,20)` the result at this index should be `False and True` i.e. `False`.
An uncommon index is `datetime(2015,05,01,20,45)`, it is only found in series `B`. The expected result is to be the value of `B` at this index, i.e. `True`.

The desired result in total looks like this:

```
result = pd.Series(index=[datetime(2015,05,01,20),
                          datetime(2015,05,01,20,15),
                          datetime(2015,05,01,20,30),
                          datetime(2015,05,01,20,45)],
                   data=[False, True, True, True])
```

### My Approach:

I came up with a good start (I think) but cannot find the correct operation, it currently looks like this

```
result = None
for next in series:
    if result is None:
        result = next
    else:
        result = result.reindex(index=result.index | next.index)
        # the next line sadly returns: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
        result.loc[next.index] = result.loc[next.index] and next.loc[next.index]  # sadly returns
```

Comment: Sorry are you looking for `A.combine_first(B)`?

Comment: @EdChum i dont think so. in this case it does give the desired result, but for instance ``B.combine_first(A)`` just overrides the ``False`` in ``B`` by the ``True`` in ``A``. I updated the question and removed the misleading ``result.update(next)``

Answer (score 0):

I should have digged a little further before asking. I found a solution, which works for me and looks like the pandas-way of doing it, but I might stand corrected if an even more convenient way is presented!

```
result = None
for next in series:
    if result is None:
        result = next
    else:
        index = result.index | next.index
        result = result.reindex(index, fill_value=True) & next.reindex(index, fill_value=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, I'd concat the 2 series column-wise and then call a function row-wise that drops the `NaN` values and returns the logical `and` of the 2 columns or the lone column value:

```
In [231]:

df = pd.concat([A,B], axis=1)
def func(x):
    l = x.dropna()
    if len(l) > 1:
        return l[0]&l[1]

    return l.values[0]
df['result'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
df
​
Out[231]:
                         0     1 result
2015-05-01 20:00:00  False  True  False
2015-05-01 20:15:00   True   NaN   True
2015-05-01 20:30:00   True  True   True
2015-05-01 20:45:00    NaN  True   True
```

Comment: Looks like it produces the desired result for exactly 2 Series. Though i think i stick with my solution as it supports an arbitrary number of series.